# Nginx changes headers of files served from an upstream server unintentionally

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a setup in which Nginx 1.15 is running as reverse proxy to an asp.net core application.
I have added some Content-Encoding headers to files served by asp.net core appliaction. I can see it is present when I send request directly to asp.net core application. But when I send request to Nginx the header(Content-Encoding) is not present!
What is the problem?

Here's nginx configuration:

```
  ##FRONTIER
server {
 listen 80;

 server_name 0.0.0.0;

 location / {
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;

   proxy_pass http://frontier_server;

   # enable WebSockets
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection "keep-alive";
 }
```

}

curl to nginx:

```
TP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 15 Apr 2019 08:19:15 GMT
Server: nginx/1.15.2
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 96381
Last-Modified: Sun, 14 Apr 2019 13:23:12 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "1d4f2c53577587d"
Age: 1
```

---

curl directly to asp.net core application:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 15 Apr 2019 08:20:48 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-gzip
Server: Kestrel
Content-Length: 96381
Content-Encoding: gzip
Last-Modified: Sun, 14 Apr 2019 13:23:12 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "1d4f2c53577587d"
```

Both nginx and the application is running inside a docker container.

nginx docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: "mynginx:2"
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
    - 3000:3000
    - 80:80
    - 4000:4000
    - 4001:4001
    - 443:443
    volumes:
    - /var/dana/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    restart: unless-stopped

networks: 
  default:
    external:
      name: dana
```

---

application docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  website:
    build: .
    container_name: website
    ports:
    - 5000:5000
    volumes:
    - /var/dana/website/appsettings.json:/app/appsettings.json
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
    - /var/dana/website/wwwroot/.well-known/:/app/wwwroot/.well-known/
    restart: unless-stopped


networks: 
  default:
    external:
      name: dana
```

Thanks

Comment: Show `curl -I http://nginx...` and `curl -I http://asp...`

Comment: @AlexeyTen Modified my question and added the requested information

Comment: Your application is behaving very strangely. Why is it claiming to serve a gzipped file that is then gzipped a second time? If that is not what it is supposed to be doing, then it is either setting the wrong Content-Encoding or Content-Type. In either case, you should stop what you're doing and talk to its developers.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am it's developer too. I did not understand you really. there are some files with .unityweb extension that are pre gzipped. All I want to do is to add Content-Encoding:gzip to the request so that I can take advantage of browser decopression.

Comment: You should set the correct MIME type in Content-Type, then. Google tells me it's `application/vnd.unity`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton , according to this: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-deploying.html
It is application/octet-stream . I modified the app to set the Content-Type to application/octet-stream . Still nginx is changing Content-Type and removing Content-Encoding

Comment: I don't see anything else in your nginx configuration that might cause this. Are you running any _other_ reverse proxy, load balancer, cache, CloudFlare, etc?

Comment: @MichaelHampton , I am running both the asp.net core app and nginx in a docker container. That's all

Comment: Please provide your docker-compose.yml and any other relevant information. Please do not wait for someone to ask for it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton , I added docker-compose files. Thanks for your time and attention

Comment: Hm, there's nothing obvious there. What's in the rest of the nginx configuration?